# Young Coral Maple in trouble

Tags: japanese-maple

Early this week I noticed one of my japanese coral maple tree go from a green to bright green, and its leaf's dropping instead of perked up. This was my third one - I had planted this one last year around this same time, following instructions from the tree shipping company (a bit of fertilizer, watered soil, planting and mulch). The only significant thing that has changed in the yard within the past two weeks are adding new black mulch (to the tree and other yard areas), and lawnmowing. Can someone please help indicate what's wrong or what can I try? This tree was doing well for an entire year. The first 4 pictures are of the tree changing from the past 5 days to today.

Some history... Why is this my third tree? Well out of first two threes, the older one had this same problem last year around this same time... it ended up dying. Back then, I tried everything (water flushing, checking moisture/watering, sun protection, soil check, lime, fertilizing, mulch) and it still died. The pictures of the dying tree from last year are at the end. The second tree was snapped by wild life earlier this year, and seems to be hanging there (added a picture)... This third one is all that I have left.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

[image]

enter image description here

[![enter image description here][8]][8]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Fertilizing" is *almost always* a dubious idea with  trees. Particularly any quickly-available type. They are not lettuce...and they are easily "burnt."

Comment: Yes but that was last year. How would that be part of the issue?

Comment: Do you fertilize the lawn that the tree is in? Or worse yet use a "weed & feed" lawn product?

Comment: No not at all. I don't do anything to the lawn. Just happened to mow it, and added mulch.

Comment: So far so good. When adding mulch, were you careful to keep the mulch from being piled right up the trunk so as not to change the effective soil line depth at the trunk?

Comment: A group of workers added the mulch... they piled it up the trunk almost two inches high. I removed it yesterday (pushed it completely away from the trunk, about one feet) after I posted this inquiry.

Comment: Can you check the brand or label of the mulch?  Some mulch is sold with chemical additives.  Also, check the bark all over to see if a worker accidentally damaged the bark.  Or a rodent might have damaged the bark.